# How to fit a div container to cover all the remaining space in between?

Tags: html, css, overflow

My center div goes out of its container, how can it take the remaining space between left and right?
Left and right have to be fully visibles, but the contents on center can be overflow hidden

[** **jsFiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2x8e/3/)

HTML

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=left>
        <div>first element</div>
        <div>second element</div>
        <div>third element</div>
    </div>
    <div id=right>right frame variable width</div>
    <div id=center>
        <div>first element</div>
        <div>second element</div>
        <div>third element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{margin:0;}
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#container {
    height:30px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    border:4px solid black;
    height:100%;
}
#left *{
    border:2px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
#center {
    float:left;
    border:4px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}
#center *{
    border:2px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    border:4px solid black;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `float:left` and `display:inline-block` from the `#center` element..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Z2x8e/8/